# How can I reference a cell using rows and colums (1,1) instead of alphabetic denotation (A1) in Excel VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, solver

Here's my VBA code for Excel Solver:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$209", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$210"
```

Equivalently, I'm trying to write something like this:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(209, 7).Value, Relation:=2, FormulaText:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(210, 7).Value
```

But this syntax is wrong. How can I write this code correctly? Later on, I'll be able to write a for-loop using this format "Cells(x,y)". Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it like this: =Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(209, 7).Address instead of =Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(209, 7).Value ?

Comment: I usually do something like: `ActiveSheet.cells(1,1).select` `ActiveCell.Value = ...`

Comment: Hey @duDE, thanks, I'll give it a try right away!